# Elmah modify current exception before logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, elmah

I have an `Asp.net MVC` project which is using `Elmah` to log the exceptions.

The project is using `Entity Framework` which can throw a `DbEntityValidationException` exception where is specifies which properties couldn't be saved into Database.

I am trying to capture that exception (as is not logged in details by Elmah), and append the info to the current exception.

The problem is that, if i modify the current exception, the changes are not captured by the `Elmah`. Instead, i have to raise another exception with the details about `DbEntityValidationException`, but this will create two consecutive errors logs.

Is possible to append some extra text to the exception before elmah logs it?

```
public class ErrorHandleAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true)
            return;

        Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;

        Exception dbEntityException = exception;
        while (dbEntityException != null && dbEntityException is System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException == false)
        {
            dbEntityException = dbEntityException.InnerException;
        }

        if (dbEntityException != null && dbEntityException is System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)
        {
            DbEntityValidationException dbEntityValidationException = dbEntityException as DbEntityValidationException;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Db Entity Validation Exception");
            foreach (var item in dbEntityValidationException.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Entity: {0} {1}", item.Entry.Entity.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
                foreach (var error in item.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1} {2}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage, Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }

            exception = new Exception(sb.ToString(), exception);
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the double logging in ELMAH, you should be able to set ExceptionHandled to true yourself, right?

Comment: I've tried that, and if i set it to true, the exception won't propagate in the IIS pipeline anymore

Comment: That's a good thing, right? This way you can log a custom exception with the right info and have the DB exception handled as an InnerException of your custom exception.